# default argument for structure reference build failed in linux

Tags: c++, linux, default-value

Well suppose there is a function

```
void fun(const MyStructure& argu1 = MyStructure(), MyStructure& argu2 = Mystructure())
```

`argu2` isn't const because I want to modify its value in the function.

To call the function:

```
MyStructure a; 
MyStructure b; 
fun(a,b);
```

The build succeeds in windows but fails in Linux and the error is

```
default argument for parameter of type 'MyStructure&' has type 'MyStructure'
```

But the build succeeds both in windows and in linux if I remove the second default argument which is non-const... Can anybody tell me why and how to solve it?

Comment: It makes no sense to have a non-const reference to a default parameter.

Comment: It works on MSVC because of a non-standard 'extension' in the MS C++ compiler that allows binding non-const references to temporary objects.

Comment: @MuriloVasconcelos most of the time people who call the function don't really care the value of argu2...so that's why i do this...do you have any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use overloading to let you manually handle an optional second non-const reference argument:

```
void fun( MyStruct const& arg1, MyStruct& arg2)
{
    // do the real work
}

void fun( MyStruct const& arg1 = MyStruct())
{
    MyStruct arg2;  // a dummy argument that can be changed, but we'll
                    //  throw those changes away
    fun( arg1, arg2);
}
```